# Cannot import http.urlsafe_base64

Tags: django, python-import

I use Django Nonrel in my project and it was running normally until today morning. The import

`from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode`

gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/paulozullu/.virtualenvs/wopik/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 101, in get_response
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/home/paulozullu/.virtualenvs/wopik/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 340, in resolve
    sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
  File "/home/paulozullu/.virtualenvs/wopik/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 224, in resolve
    return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
  File "/home/paulozullu/.virtualenvs/wopik/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 231, in callback
    self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
  File "/home/paulozullu/.virtualenvs/wopik/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 31, in wrapper
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/paulozullu/.virtualenvs/wopik/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 98, in get_callable
    mod = import_module(mod_name)
  File "/home/paulozullu/.virtualenvs/wopik/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/paulozullu/dev/workspaces/wopik/pages/views.py", line 11, in <module>
    from accounts.views import saveExternalUserGraph
  File "/home/paulozullu/dev/workspaces/wopik/accounts/views.py", line 14, in <module>
    from accounts.forms import FormChangePassword, FormEditUser, FormUser,\
  File "/home/paulozullu/dev/workspaces/wopik/accounts/forms.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode
ImportError: cannot import name urlsafe_base64_encode
```

**Solution**

I just reinstalled django-nonrel 1.5.11 and now everything is ok.

Comment: Are you running a very old version of Django? The `urlsafe_base64_encode` method was added in Django 1.6.

Comment: Perhaps you did not activate the local environment, and as a result, the system uses the globally installed one?

Comment: @alasdair I'm using Django 1.5.11 . My team mate uses the same version and everything is ok. I use this version because it's the newest compatible with mongoengine.

Comment: @willem-van-onsem No. It's already activated.

Comment: As I said, `urlsafe_base64_encode` was added in Django 1.6, so that import in your `wopik/accounts/forms.py` is simply not going to work in Django 1.5.X. If your colleague does not get the error, then either they are using a different version of Django, or they have a different version of `wopik/accounts/forms.py` which does not contain that import. Note that both Django 1.5.x and 1.6.x are years out of date and do not receive bug fixes or security updates.

Comment: @Alasdair I just reinstalled django-nonrel 1.5.11 and now everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

For Django 3:

```
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode
```

[docs.djangoproject.com](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.http)